# SQL Server join query - assistance needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table `employee_travel` where I need to identify departure location and date for each employee and find out what the arrival date is when the employee comes back to the initial location. I know the data is poor / insufficient. I still need to fetch the data in below format. Please help.

[image]

I want the output to be like this:

[image]

Comment: So, what is your question, what have you tried, and why didn't it work, or what was the research you performed and what about it didn't you understand?

Comment: Do employees always start from the same city?

Comment: @Gordon: No employees do not start from same city

Comment: @curiousboy . . . As I recommend in my answer, I think you should ask a *new* question if that is the case, along with sample data and desired results -- but not as an image.  Images are not helpful.

Comment: Sorry my bad. i misread your question. yes each employee will start from his own city every time.  i will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: There is no such thing as "his home city" in your schema - that is an assumption you make and that "fact" depends on the rows you consider and include in your "calculation". If you were to examine rows from Apr 2 2020, what would you expect? Surely you don't want to process years of rows every time you need this information. And if employee moves to a new "home city" - what then?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it in two steps, first we add the Arrival date and ticket_id to every Departure.

And second, we only return the Departures of new cycles, checking that their ticket_id is greater than every previous arrival ticket_id.

```
with DeparturesAndArrivals as (
  select Departure.Ticket_ID, Departure.Employee, Departure.[From], Departure.Departure, 
         Arrival.Departure as Arrival, Arrival.Ticket_ID as Arrival_Ticket_ID
  from employee_travel as Departure
       outer apply (select top 1 Ticket_ID, Departure
                    from employee_travel as Arrival
                    where Arrival.Employee = Departure.Employee and
                          Arrival.[To] = Departure.[From] and
                          Arrival.Ticket_ID > Departure.Ticket_ID
                    order by Arrival.Ticket_ID) as Arrival
)
select Ticket_ID, Employee, [From], Departure, Arrival
from DeparturesAndArrivals as Departures
where Ticket_ID > (select coalesce(max(PreviousArrivals.Arrival_Ticket_ID), -1)
                   from DeparturesAndArrivals as PreviousArrivals
                   where PreviousArrivals.Employee = Departures.Employee and
                         PreviousArrivals.Ticket_ID < Departures.Ticket_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the employees always start from the same city -- as in your example -- you can enumerate the trips by the number of times the original city is found.  Then the rest is aggregation:

```
select distinct employee,
       first_value(ticket) over (partition by employee, trip_number order by departure) as ticket,
       from,
       min(departure) over (partition by employee, trip_number) as departure, 
       max(departure) over (partition by employee, trip_number) as arrival
from (select et.*,
             sum(case when from = first_from then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by employee order by departure) as trip_number
      from (select et.*,
                   first_value(from) over (partition by employee order by departure) as first_from
            from employee_travel et
           ) et
     ) et;
```

The problem becomes significantly different if trips can start from different locations for the same employee.  If that is actually the case, I would recommend asking a *new* question.  Provide sample data and desired results as *text* tables in the question -- and a db/SQL fiddle is also helpful.